# MVC Forms LoginUrl is incorrect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application with forms authentication. For some reason that I cannot see, the login redirect url is `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fSecure%2fAction` instead of `/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fSecure%2fAction`. The difference is subtle, its using /Account/**Login** instead of /Account/**LogOn**.

My web.config forms section is correct. Would else could possibly affect the login url??

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="720" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was going insane!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FormsAuthentication LoginUrl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447728/formsauthentication-loginurl)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is a known issue. I had the same problem with my custom authorize attribute. I found the solution somewhere on the net, can't remember where. Just add this to `appSettings` in your `web.config`

```
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/LogOn" />
```

*Note:* This works with MVC 3, I didn't try it with previous versions.

**EDIT:**
Found it mentioned in [release notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230), but it seems that they've changed the setting name and forgot to update release notes for RTM version.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure why I hadn't come across this before. I've created a few MVC 3 apps but never had this issue.

Comment: So I'm running my MVC 3 app and if I change <forms loginUrl="~/{geo_code}/Account/LogOn" it (FormsAuthentication?) actually attempts the redirect, and I get a 404 because {geo_code} was meant to be replaced with a special code.

I'm not seeing this appSettings loginUrl key working...

Comment: I had this suddenly happen after running aspnet_regiis. Thank you so much, I'd have been sunk without this knowledge as searching my project found no references to "login".

Comment: Thanks for this. I previously had:
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
which I then also removed when adding:
<add key="loginUrl" value="~/Account/LogOn" />

Comment: Been looking for hours for a solution thanks for that

Answer (score 15):

I ran into a similar problem sometime ago. After a few months I discovered the root of the problem: I had added a 'deployable dependency' on 'ASP.NET Web Pages with Razor Syntax'. This adds a reference to: `WebMatrix.Data.dll` 
This assembly has a class with a static constructor that does the following:

```
static FormsAuthenticationSettings()
{
 FormsAuthenticationSettings.LoginUrlKey = "loginUrl";
 FormsAuthenticationSettings.DefaultLoginUrl = "~/Account/Login";
}
```

Check if you are referencing this dll.

Answer (score 9):

frennky's answer helped me get to this. I needed all of these in my web.config:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Authentication/LogOn" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Authentication/LogOn" timeout="2880"></forms>
   </authentication>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks. It's working now.
Thing is you have to add both settings. Otherwise it's not working.

Comment: I tried but for the area and it's not working for me

Answer (score 7):

To fix this problem, which still exist in MVC 3 you have to remove the WebMatrix.*.dll from _bin_deployableAssemblies and bin folders respectively.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me in other, newer, MVC3 projects.

Comment: You deserve the glory

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you and thank you! This solved our problem where trying to use IdentifyServer4, it would not run the IdentityProvider code, and instead would redirect to /Account/Login even though this was not declared anywhere. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Authentication/LogOn" />
</appSettings>
```

You could use this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

It worked for me.

Comment: doesn't worked for me, tried in area, instead I got error saying The 'PreserveLoginUrl' is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Is it originating from the redirect contained within your LogOn action result?

Search your project for the string LogIn and you may find where it is specified?

Comment: No, its not getting to /Account/LogOn. I get a 404 at /Account/Login.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue (like 6 years later and this page doesn't rank high in searches anymore...) my fix was similar to santiagoIT.

Because I added authentication to a project that didn't previously have it I pretty much "cheated" by copying required authentication code from a default project template which included:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"), 
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

The forms authentication url was using web.config for all my aspx pages but bombed when I added the Authorize attribute.

Changing the LoginPath fixed my issue.

Comment: That's actually a different issue since you're using asp.net Identity, the modern way to handle authentication.

Answer (score 0):

After Trying Many technique in .net MVC 5 in VS2015  I ended up here.

Its was hard to understand but yet very Simple.
Whatever we code within Form loginURL was later removed OR replaced by the web.config itself.And this line in the Web.Config does it.

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication"/>
```

Comment the line out in web.config and then it won't go to "Account/Login" automatically. I tested in VS2015 and it works like a charm. :)