# loginUrl redirect to somewhere else

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an asp.net mvc application which was working properly before I click on "Add deploy able dependencies". Cause I had some problems on deployment server, I had to click on that option. After doing so, the authentication part in web.config does not work properly :

Instead of redirecting me to ~/Admin/LogIn it redirects me to Account/Login?...

I read these useful links, like http://forums.asp.net/p/1613705/4128618.aspx, And I applied the solution in server.

But my question here is that why my application does not work any more in my local machine as before, without having problem with authentication redirection ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, it may be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447728/formsauthentication-loginurl/6452419#6452419

Comment: @frennky,Thanks. I had already saw this, and I know it fixes my problem, but it does not satisfy the question I asked.