# Redirecting to Login Page with Attribute Routing in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following:

```
    [Route("login")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

However, when I navigate to any [Authorized] route as an unauthenticated user, I get navigated to `/Account/Login`, which is an invalid route thanks to me overriding it to `login`.  How do I tell MVC5 to use the attribute routes when redirecting in this case?

Comment: In your web.config under `system.web->authentication->forms` there is an attribute `loginUrl` - what is that equal to on yours?

Comment: @wal - even if I change that from the default `Account/Login` to `login`, I get redirected to `Account/Login`

Comment: and when you navigate directly to `your-domain.com/login`?  could you have left an `[Authorized]` attr on the controller or base controller?

Comment: /login works, I want it to redirect, just to /login, not the default Account/Login, because Account/Login does not work.

Comment: And even if I had, `[AllowAnonymous]` should negate that, no?

Comment: yes probably would negate it actually (have not checked) -

Comment: i am surprised you are redirected even tho you have changed `loginUrl` - what happens if you change loginUrl to something else, say something invalid like `~/doesnotexist` ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - try overriding an MVC controller action with attribute routing, and then navigate to the default action's route, and you'll understand.

Comment: @wal - I still get /Account/Login :/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447728/formsauthentication-loginurl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Startup.Auth` there is a setting I had to change:

```
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
```