# MVC 3 default register link not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVC Forms LoginUrl is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073445/mvc-forms-loginurl-is-incorrect)

I have deployed the simple mvc 3 to IIS 7.5.
The register redirect url is */Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fRegister*. 
It does not redirect to registration web page.

It seems like the Logon problem as the thread:
[MVC Forms LoginUrl is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073445/mvc-forms-loginurl-is-incorrect)

Comment: **Thanks for the kindly responses**. I try remove all reference and add again. It is **solved**. No extra configuration on web.config. It work well now.

Answer (score 0):

From ASP.NET MVC 3 Release Notes :

> There’s a known issue that causes Forms Authentication to always
>   redirect unauthenticated users to ~/Account/Login, ignoring the forms
>   authentication setting used in Web.config. The workaround is to add
>   the following app setting.
>
> ```
> <add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false" />
> ```

Check yourself out :

http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have added the key but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind is if you have checked if your register method is without the `AuthorizeAttribute`?
Maybe you've put the AuthorizeAtrtribute on top of the controller or you you've created a BaseController with the attribute, so every controller deriving from it need the user to be authenticated

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have checked it. There is not AuthorizeAttribute and BaseController I derived.