# MVC Html ActionLink Url error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, html.actionlink

I have two views in my **MVC 2** `Login` and `Register`

In my `Login.aspx` i have added

```
    <td>Click here to <%: Html.ActionLink("[Register]", "Register") %></td>
```

However I am getting `ReturnUrl=%2fViews%2fHome%2fRegister` in my address bar redirecting it back to `Login`.

I referred this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555870/mvc-3-default-register-link-not-work) and made corresponding changes in my web config but no luck.

But when in my config I changed ,

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
```

to

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Register" timeout="2880" />
```

It worked.

I haven't changed anything in `Global.asax.cs` file. How can i navigate to my Register view using `Html Action Link` ??

**Note: I am using MVC 2**

Thank you All

Comment: I think it have to be `<% Html.ActionLink("Register","Register") %>`

Comment: @Vinh No it doesnt work

Comment: Hmm, I forgot add : in the code, but I think you know it, don't you. I use MVC 2 too, and I think basically it should work
`<%: Html.ActionLink("text", "ActionMethod", "ControllerName")%>`

Comment: If then, I think you should check Authorize in register page, controller, it's may cause your problem. If the way you use ActionLink is right, something have to be wrong

Answer (score 1):

What comes to mind is if you have checked if your register method is without the AuthorizeAttribute? Maybe you've put the AuthorizeAtrtribute on top of the controller or you you've created a BaseController with the attribute, so every controller deriving from it need the user to be authenticated

Comment: +1 That was my first thought too. Do not set the [Authorize] Attribute over the controller, if you need to access a method without logging in. Instead, just add a attribute on every single method a guest isnt allowed to see.

Comment: In MVC2 [allow anonymous] is not working otherwise you need to just decorate the register method with this and your requirement is fulfill