# Default Login asp.net MVC3 redirect to wrong view. Where is this set?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I am having issues with the redirect to log in page when a user tries to access a page needing authorization. For some reason It wants to direct to:

```
http://domain.com/Account/Login
```

When it should redirect to:

```
http://domain.com/Account/LogOn
```

I believe I have set it correctly in the web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

but for some reason it still redirects incorrectly. I have also searched for "Login" in my entire solution and see no other place where Account/Login would be specified.

How can I fix it to redirect correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is a known issue when using deployable assemblies with MVC3.

I found the solution in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073445/mvc-forms-loginurl-is-incorrect).